# VBA: Insert number of rows based on cell value

Tags: excel, vba

Looking for a way to insert X rows above cell B9 in my workbook. The value of X will change and can be found in cell B4. This seems very simple, but I can't get this portion of my code to work.

```
ActiveSheet.Range("B9").Select
Selection.EntireRow.Insert.Cells("B4"), CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromRightOrBelow
```

Comment: You don't need to `Select`. Try `Range("B9").EntireRow.Resize(Range("B4").Value).Insert CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromRightOrBelow`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Resize` to do that, and you don't need to `Select` at all.

```
Range("B9").EntireRow.Resize(Range("B4").Value).Insert CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromRightOrBelow
```

Also, you should avoid `ActiveSheet` — instead, fully qualify the sheet using `Sheets("YourSheetName")` or a variable referencing the sheet in question.